# How to fix Safari Browser page refresh issue while trying paste content from Clipboard in a Content Security Policy enabled server?

Tags: css, ios, mobile-safari, clipboard, content-security-policy

In one of my project I am using Nginx server and write the few line of code to include Content Security Policy:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' img-src 'self' data:; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; object-  src 'none'; media-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
```

My primary purpose is to skip inline CSS, in file CSS and JS script. In a certain page the app send an OTP in mobile and allow to type or copy-paste the code to process further. All the functionality is working fine in PC browser, Android browser, other browsers in iOS, but the problem raise when I tried to use the app in Safari browser. In the input OTP page, if I tried to paste the OTP from the clipboard, safari force the page to reload. If I remove CSP from my Nginx then the page reload issue is solved. I am not sure but I believe the issue lies somewhere in CSP (most probably no, as all other browser works) or in Safari browser or in iOS clipboard.

Does anyone help me to figure out what maybe the root cause that trigger Safari browser to force a webpage to reload while trying to paste a code from Clipboard?

- Thanks

Comment: I'd start by checking if any CSP _violations_ are reported in that situation. Access to a browser console might be difficult in mobile Safari, not sure if you can hook it up in some kind of remote debugging setup, to get access. If not, implement reporting as part of the CSP, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#enabling_reporting

Comment: (If it wasn't _mobile_ Safari, I'd say try and check without any browser extensions that might be installed - something like a password manager for example could be injecting its own scripts, that interfere with an OTP input field. But I guess in mobile Safari, there are no extensions to begin with?)

Comment: After manual testing, what I found is: `script-src 'self';` force safari browser to reload a page rather paste data from clipboard in iOS/iPhone.